A woman writes, directs and acts in a movie about herself having too much sex, drugs and rock and roll
This movie was probably made about 10 years ago. It was shown maybe 5 years ago on Australian SBS and is probably Italian.
It was a film by someone who wasn't famous but just an average teenager once. Somehow by her twenties, she must have studied film and then wrote this script about herself in her younger days. I suppose somehow she must have been given the money to make the film, so she then acted herself and directed the film by herself.
It was about her past, when she apparently had too much sex, drugs and rock and roll. The critics said it was self-indulgent crap so I didn't watch it but thinking about it again, it seems a most interesting theme and I'd like to see it even if it is against the critics' recommendations.

I think I know what you're after, but some more details would help: Who's 'she\her\herself', exactly? Someone famous? Do you remember any specific scenes or other plot details?

No she wasn't famous but just an average teenager except in her opinion she had too much of s,d,and rnr. Some how by her twenties, she must have studied film, she then writes this script about herself and her younger days. I suppose somehow she must have been given the money to make the film, so she then acts herself and directs the film herself.

I see. Well, in the film I had in mind, she's kind of famous. Everything else fits, though, so I might as well put it up.

All clues point to Scarlet Diva from 2000, an Italian movie about the life of Asia Argento, who also stars in it, wrote it and directed it. She was 25 at the time. From Wikipedia (Warning: Risque Poster):

Scarlet Diva is a semi-autobiographical film about the Italian actress and director Asia Argento's life as an actress. A self-destructive streak in Anna Batista (Argento) pulls her into drugs, sex and other excesses. [...] She falls in love with an uncaring Australian rock and roll star (Jean Shepard), then finds out she is pregnant by him. 

Several critics called it a self-indulgent vanity project. And the movie aired on SBS in late April, 2010. Here's the trailer:




Thanks for that. Yes, I think you are right. I didn't watch it in 2010 and so my mind over the years must have construed something a little different from the facts. It is still an interesting concept but whether the film is worth watching, well that is another matter.

@Bob No problem. :) If this is the correct answer, don't forget to approve it by clicking on the check mark

You probably mean the movie "Thirteen"
The summary reads: 

A thirteen-year-old girl's relationship with her mother is put to the test as she discovers drugs, sex, and petty crime in the company of her cool but troubled best friend.

With "she" you probably mean the actress Nikki Reed.
Imdb has to say: 

Is this an autobiography of Nikki Reed's life at 13?
It is a combination of fact and fiction. It seems that there were situations 
      that were perhaps dramatized a bit for the screen, to help move the story 
      along, and also situations that were true. By the age of 12, she became 
      rebellious and experimented with sex, drugs, and alcohol.
By 14 (post-film), she became emancipated and moved out of her mothers house 
      to live on her own. Since then, she has recovered and had a successful 
      career in Hollywood.
However, Nikki Reed has stated in interviews since then that this 
      information is false. According to her, the marketing scheme was that it was 
      autobiographical, but in fact it was not. She was influenced by her 
      management to say it was based on fact, but she has never taken drugs and 
      she didn't drink or have sex at that age. She does admit to being "nasty" to 
      her mother and self-harming, so it was loosely based on her life, with major 
      differences.
Did Nikki Reed write this herself?
She co-wrote it with Catherine Hardwicke, the director of the movie. They 
      wrote the screenplay in 6 days.

I found this by googling "youth sex drugs actress playing herself".

Thanks but no, it wasn't the film Thirteen.
